# Python Django - delaying ValidationError until for loop completes

Tags: python, for-loop, validation, if-statement, error-handling

I'm working on an app that simulates a social media site. I currently have a form where users can enter in their friends' emails so they can be invited to join the app.

Let's say we have a user who enters in three email addresses to the email form which are then saved as a list of strings:

```
emails_to_invite = ["jen@website.com", "mike@website.com", "joe@website.com"]
```

In the database, we already have a list of users who have already been invited to the site:

```
current_users = ["jen@website.com", "mike@website.com", "dan@website.com", "kim@website.com"]
```

So we have two users who have already been invited: jen@website.com and mike@website.com.

I'm trying to write some code that returns a ValidationError and can list both matched users in the message. Here's what I have so far:

```
for email in emails_to_invite:
 if email in current_users:
  raise forms.ValidationError(f"{email} is already in the database.")
```

Here's how I want this error to display:

```
jen@website.com is already in the database.
mike@website.com is already in the database.
```

But right now, the error only displays the first email:

```
jen@website.com is already in the database.
```

I also need mike@website.com to display too. It appears that the for loop stops once it recognizes one match, but I need it to keep going until it recognizes all matches. Can anyone offer some suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want an `Exception` in a code-block to halt your execution (and hide further exceptions, as you've found), put the susceptible code in a a `try/except` block to handle the error as you see fit.

To later raise the exception, consider using something like:

```py
raised_exceptions = []
<loop that might raise exceptions>
  try:
    <loop that might raise exceptions>
  except Exception as e:
    raised_exceptions.append(e)

<do something with the exceptions you saved>
```

That being said, IMO you shouldn't be using exceptions in this way - consider returning a series of lists, one per possible outcome, instead: `email sent` and `already invited` (and/or `joined user`)